# Usable driver/software for Brother all-in-one inkjet MFC-J480DW

Tags: printing

I have a printer that is no longer compatible with the new operating systems. It is very important to me as it has the ability to scan and print film strips and negatives. There are no current printer drivers available to enable printing in Windows 10.

I have come across a program for scanners, VueScan, which makes obsolete scanners able to work with current operating systems. I would like to know if there are any programs like this available for printers? The printer I am using now, **Brother all-in-one inkjet MFC-J480DW**, is on the verge of becoming obsolete as they are discontinuing updating the printer drivers. I have unused printer inkjet cartridges that will not be able to be used and a waste of money.

Is there any program or way in which to continue using my printers even though the manufacturer has stopped updating their printer drivers? As both of my printers are all-in-ones, would the VueScan program apply to the printing feature along with the scanning it makes possible to use with new operating systems? Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a hold-over or a last ditch resort, but consider that you could install a virtual machine to match the operating system supporting your printer. I've not had to use a VM for this purpose, which means it would be a ground-up experiment. If it works, it gives you the means to empty the ink cartridges rather than tossing them in the bin.

I can confirm that VueScan supports only the scanning aspect of the device and has zero impact on the printing portion.

Comment: Thank you for the info re VueScan. Now to find a program like that for printers!